# Как заставить nginx передать OPTIONS запрос в PHP?

Tags: php, nginx, веб-сервер

По какой то причине nginx отвечает на запросы OPTIONS кодом 405 и стандартной страницей ошибки nginx. Как заставить nginx передать запрос в php?

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        charset utf8;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!NULL:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

sites-avalible/example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/temoffey/.acme.sh/example.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/temoffey/.acme.sh/example.com/example.com.key;

    include snippets/ssl-headers.conf;
    include snippets/csp-headers-frame.conf;

    index index.html index.php;
    root /srv/nginx/example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

    var_dump($_SERVER);

?>
```

Comment: Конфиг nginx в студию

Comment: Скорей всего маршруты на options не настроены в вашем php фреймворке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге отказался от nginx+php в сторону node.js